# Infinitely generates text on a canvas in different position (Tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas

I know my purpose is extremely simple but it just won't work in my code. I need to place this "HELLO" text in a different position (down 100 every time). I'm trying to use the 'after' method but it won't do anything. The result is that the canvas will show up with a white background with only the text in position 100, 100. The position just won't change (even after 10 seconds). Please tell me where went wrong.

**Here is my code:**

```py
from tkinter import *
import time

def create():

    global y_position
    y_position = 100

    word = canvas.create_text (100, y_position, text = 'HELLO')

    y_position += y_position + 100
    
    root.after(500, create)
    
root = Tk ()

canvas = Canvas (root, height = 1200, width = 800, bg = 'white')
canvas.pack()

root.after(0, create)

mainloop()
```

Comment: You are explicitly resetting the y coordinate to 100 every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this (I'm not sure if that's what you're intending on doing but it will create a new "HELLO" text every 500 milliseconds below the last iteration by 100):

```
from tkinter import *
import time
y_position = 100
def create():

    global y_position
    

    word = canvas.create_text (100, y_position, text = 'HELLO')

    y_position += 100
    
    root.after(500, create)
    
root = Tk ()

canvas = Canvas (root, height = 1200, width = 800, bg = 'white')
canvas.pack()

root.after(0, create)

mainloop()
```